# laravel how to make middleware redirect

Tags: php, redirect, laravel-5

I have create form for user to comment in my post but I want need check Auth has Login before submit the form. How can i do that ?

For me I have use middleware to protect it, But If use not login it redirect to Login Form when user has been login it is not redirect back to posts route`/show-posts/{post}`,It redirect to back to route`/comments` . How can i solve this ?

URL Show Single Post

```
Route::get( '/show-post/{post}', 'HomePageController@single_show')
     ->name('home.post.show' );
```

URL form Comments form

```
Route::resource('/comments', 'CommentsController');
```

CommentsController

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->middleware( 'auth')->except(['index', 'show']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a middleware class and redirect like so:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectToComments
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            return redirect()->route('comments');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

That is the general form of redirection through middleware, simply modify which route to redirect to or add more conditional logic as needed.

Comment: I need redirect to comments form in single post.How to redirect it to route " /show-post/{post}. How to know parameter post to redirect back.

Example I'm in url `/Show-post/{ 1 }` in this url i have form for comment, But when user submit form, User is not login and it redirect to login when user done login I need to redirect user back to url `/show-post/{ 1 }`. How could i this?